# Commerce programatically Create Order with Customer Profile

Tags: entities, commerce

I am using this method to create order successfully, how do I add a customer profile with all the country/address etc to this order?

There does not seem to be any reference to customer profiles in commerce_order_save. I had a peek into the commerce_order database table and it also must be hidden in data.

```
function create_order_with_products($product_ids, $uid) {
    $order = commerce_order_new($uid, 'pending');

    // Save the order so its ID is assigned.
    commerce_order_save($order);

    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);

    //add products to order by ids array
    foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ){
        $product = commerce_product_load($product_id);

        // Create a line item with quantity 1 and this product.
        $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, 1, $order->order_id);

        // Save the line item to get its ID.
        commerce_line_item_save($line_item);

        // Add the line item to the order using the wrapper.
        $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;
    }

  // Save the order.
  commerce_order_save($order);

//somehow attach the profile to the order????
$profile = commerce_customer_profile_load(exampleID);

//How do I use this wrapper maybe?
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
$wrapper->{????????} = $profile;

      return $order;
    }


  // Ensure the attached line items are associated with the order if they do not
  // have an order_id set yet.
  foreach (entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order)->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {
    if ($line_item_wrapper->order_id->value() == 0) {
      $line_item_wrapper->order_id = $order->order_id;
      $line_item_wrapper->save();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please see the following example: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89412/programmatically-creating-an-order-in-drupal-commerce-for-anonymous-users-redire/102920

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After running a debug on the $order object in the commerce_order.controller.inc save method it was simple to work out the right format for the data. But this is probably not best practice but is useful for generating a bunch of orders.

```
function create_order_with_products ( $product_ids , $uid, $profile_id ) {
    $order = commerce_order_new ( $uid , 'pending' );

    // Save the order so its ID is assigned.
    commerce_order_save ( $order );

    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper ( 'commerce_order' , $order );

    //add products to order by ids array
    foreach ( $product_ids as $product_id ) {
        $product = commerce_product_load ( $product_id );

        // Create a line item with quantity 1 and this product.
        $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new ( $product , 1 , $order->order_id );

        // Save the line item to get its ID.
        commerce_line_item_save ( $line_item );

        // Add the line item to the order using the wrapper.
        $order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[ ] = $line_item;
    }

    //create the right array for the save controller
    $profile_object = array ( 
        'und' => array ( array ( 'profile_id' => $profile_id , ) , ) , ); 

    $order->commerce_customer_billing = $profile_object;

    // Save the order.
    commerce_order_save ( $order );


    return $order;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally find if something isn't documented, the best way to work out how to do it is by looking at someone else's code! Here's how a customer profile is added to an order in the commerce_customer module:

```
/**
 * Checkout pane callback: submits a customer profile edit form.
 */
function commerce_customer_profile_pane_checkout_form_submit($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
  $profile = $form_state['values'][$checkout_pane['pane_id']]['customer_profile'];

  // Ensure the profile is active.
  $profile->status = TRUE;

  // Set the profile's uid if it's being created at this time.
  if (empty($profile->profile_id)) {
    $profile->uid = $order->uid;
  }

  // Notify field widgets.
  field_attach_submit('commerce_customer_profile', $profile, $form[$checkout_pane['pane_id']], $form_state);

  // Save the profile.
  commerce_customer_profile_save($profile);

  // Store the profile ID for the related field as specified on the settings form.
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);

  if ($field_name = variable_get('commerce_' . $checkout_pane['pane_id'] . '_field', '')) {
    $wrapper->{$field_name} = $profile;
  }
  else {
    // Or make the association in the order's data array if no field was found.
    $order->data['profiles'][$checkout_pane['pane_id']] = $profile->profile_id;
  }
}
```

That's assuming you have the order profile ready to go. I won't go on posting a load of code on how to do that, however you should be able to find an implementation somewhere.

Comment: thanks but I am finding this hard to get closer to a solution. Out of the code in that submit handler how is that relevant to commerce_order_save($order);

Comment: Essentially you have to add the profile ID you want to associate with the order to the $order->data['profiles'] as you can see at bottom of the code. In practice it may be a bit more complex than that - you'd have to decide which lines in the code are relevant. You should probably be adding the customer profile ID before you save the order.

Comment: Yes your assumption was correct I just over thought the complexity here, all I needed to do was debug the $order from the controller and work out the correct format to put it all in.