# Drupal Commerce: Set Order as Paid in Full

Tags: 7, commerce

I am trying to import records from a CSV file (from another non-drupal database) for a membership site I am porting to Drupal 7. I have Drupal Commerce, Commerce Recurring Framework set up. Everything works as it should when you go through the proper work flow. However, I have 2000+ records that need to be added to the site and going through that process doesn't make sense. In other words, I am writing a script to set up the order and then recurring entity for each user.

I have code that creates my order, the issue is that Commerce is looking for a payment to be made before it creates the recurring entity for the order. Again, that doesn't make sense from a time perspective, not to mention all of these members have already paid as these are being ported. So my question is how to I trigger the order paid in full event that will trigger the creation of the recurring entity being created? Or is there a way to just create the recurring entity?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
foreach ($records as $record) {
$product_sku = $record['sku'];

$order = commerce_order_new($user->uid, 'completed');

commerce_order_save($order);

$product = commerce_product_load_by_sku($product_sku);
$line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, 1, $order->order_id); 

commerce_line_item_save($line_item);

$order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);
$order_wrapper->commerce_line_items[] = $line_item;

commerce_order_save($order);
}
?>
```

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: Why are you trying to trigger that event? If you're importing these orders, why can't you just load and execute the rule directly as part of the import process?

Comment: I don't see how. I couldn't find a rule that actually created the recurring entity. As far as I could get I could see that once the order was paid for (0 balance) then the entity would create. Thoughts?

Comment: I assumed there was a rule from your description of your problem. If there isn't, then just invoke the same code the module is using to do the processing.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to trigger the paid in full event you just need to make the order balance 0. You can do that by adding a payment transaction for the full amount to the order. The event is then triggered when that new successful transaction is saved.

The relevant Commerce function is

[`commerce_payment_commerce_payment_transaction_insert`](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!commerce!modules!payment!commerce_payment.module/function/commerce_payment_commerce_payment_transaction_insert/DC)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_commerce_payment_transaction_insert().
 *
 * When a new payment transaction is inserted that is already completed, check
 * the order balance and invoke a Rules event if the order is paid in full.
 */
function commerce_payment_commerce_payment_transaction_insert($transaction) {
  // If the inserted transaction was marked as a success and placed against a
  // valid order...
  if ($transaction->status == COMMERCE_PAYMENT_STATUS_SUCCESS &&
    $order = commerce_order_load($transaction->order_id)) {
    // Then check to make sure the event hasn't been invoked for this order.
    if (empty($order->data['commerce_payment_order_paid_in_full_invoked'])) {
      // Check the order balance and invoke the event.
      $balance = commerce_payment_order_balance($order);

      if ($balance['amount'] <= 0) {
        // Invoke the event including a hook of the same name.
        rules_invoke_all('commerce_payment_order_paid_in_full', $order, $transaction);

        // Update the order's data array to indicate this just happened.
        $order->data['commerce_payment_order_paid_in_full_invoked'] = TRUE;

        // Save the updated order.
        commerce_order_save($order);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The key part is here:

```
// Invoke the event including a hook of the same name.
rules_invoke_all('commerce_payment_order_paid_in_full', $order, $transaction);
// Update the order's data array to indicate this just happened.
$order->data['commerce_payment_order_paid_in_full_invoked'] = TRUE;

// Save the updated order.
commerce_order_save($order);
```

In any case, you'll need to create a valid transaction for the order to trigger the `commerce_payment_order_paid_in_full` event. Rules reacting to that event will expect the transaction object as an assumed parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the example from `commerce_payment_example` module e.g.

```
<?php

  commerce_checkout_complete($order);

  if ($is_cli) {
    drush_print('Marking order as fully paid...');
  }

  $payment_method = commerce_payment_method_instance_load('commerce_payment_example|commerce_payment_commerce_payment_example');

  if (!$payment_method) {
    if ($is_cli) {
      drush_print("  No example payment method found, we can't mark order as fully paid. Please enable commerce_payment_example module to use this feature.");
    }
  }
  else {
    if ($is_cli) {
      drush_print("  Creating example transaction...");
    }

    // Creating new transaction via commerce_payment_example module.
    $charge      = $order->commerce_order_total['und'][0];

    $transaction = commerce_payment_transaction_new('commerce_payment_example', $order->order_id);
    $transaction->instance_id = $payment_method['instance_id'];
    $transaction->amount = $charge['amount'];
    $transaction->currency_code = $charge['currency_code'];
    $transaction->status = COMMERCE_PAYMENT_STATUS_SUCCESS;
    $transaction->message = 'Name: @name';
    $transaction->message_variables = array('@name' => 'Example payment');

    if ($is_cli) {
      drush_print("  Notifying Commerce about new transaction...");
    }

    commerce_payment_transaction_save($transaction);

    commerce_payment_commerce_payment_transaction_insert($transaction);
```

For full working example, please see:

[Programmatically creating an order in Drupal Commerce for anonymous users redirecting to payment page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89412/programmatically-creating-an-order-in-drupal-commerce-for-anonymous-users-redire/102920)