# When anonymous user adds product to cart, redirect to checkout and skip the cart, using rules

Tags: 7, commerce

I thought it was easy using Rules to skip the cart and redirect to the checkout page, but for anonymous users the URL is something like /checkout/64244
So I have no clue what destination I should use for the redirect.
Any other approaches to skip the cart are welcome..

Comment: What do you want to happen for authenticated users, also skip the cart, or not?

Comment: You might find your answer at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89412/programmatically-creating-an-order-in-drupal-commerce-for-anonymous-users-redire